# git add . add all the changes including the ignored flles

Tags: git, android-studio

I change some files in the IDE, package name, and other files. and I need to commit these changes so  I tried:

```
git add . --force
```

and it worked, but after that when I try to add some files to the staging area using just:

```
git add .
```

it will add all the files generated by the IDE "ignored files" when I try to push changes I notice that the commit size is too large!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git add . --force` added all files recursively **including ignored**; that's what `--force` is. Added files are tracked and no longer ignored; **`git` only ignores untracked files**.

To ignore the files you need to **remove them from the repository** using `git rm --cached`. Perhaps even from history using `git rebase`; but then you'll need `git push --force`.

Comment: when I use git rm --cached it tells me to specify a file, should I specify all the ignored files?

Comment: Yes, all files to be ignored.